# X11/VNC mouse pointer jitter

Tags: x11, vnc, x11vnc

I have the following setup:

1. From Windows, I connect to a VNC server initialized in a CentOS 7 machine under network A.
2. Inside this VNC session, I have a terminal from network B that had its display changed in order to be shown in this VNC session.

Explaining topic 2:

1. From any machine, I ssh to network B, then;
2. Execute `xterm -display vnc_server_addr:display &`;
3. This xterm is now visible on the above VNC session initialized under network A.

Why do I do this? Because I want a terminal from network B in my VNC session that can only be initialized in network A.

The thing is, all the GUI windows that I open from network B xterm inside my VNC session are causing my mouse to jitter like below. As an example, opening Chrome from network B xterm:

[image]

The mouse pointer keeps going back and forth, maybe due to network latency, not sure. At the beginning of this GIF animation, I'm with the mouse stopped... It's very annoying. I would rather have a slow mouse pointer than a jittering one.

What could be causing this? Is there a way to work around it somehow?

Comment: Note that the latest version of Windows Subsystem for Linux (read: Ubuntu running inside Windows) has a X11 server as well as openssh binaries.  The X11 server is enabled by default under Windows 11.  You should be able to get the xterm directly on your desktop without the VNC intermediary if set up correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! The only problem is that this Windows machine is a very controlled one. It's still win10 and I can't install wsl nor vcxsrv :(
Also there are some network restrictions that only RealVNC can access the target IP address.

Comment: You should have OpenSSh which can tunnel The X11 display.  Talk to those that has locked the machine down and say you need an X11 server on the Windows machine.

Comment: This is a veeery restricted environment. SSH is simply not allowed, I already asked. Lately, many companies are giving way to VNCs instead of SSH in other to better control data flow (mainly due to export regulations and leaks). SSH is really not an option.

Comment: Try using another Vnc client then.

Comment: Yeah, I can ask IT about it. Maybe it's feasible. I know there are some restrictions based on app (need to be RealVNC), but perhaps it can be changed. But Ideally, it would be nice to have a solution to this mouse issue...

Comment: My guess is that the particular vnc you use is not optimized for Remote Desktop and what is normally so fast that you don’t notice it, now isn’t.   I would suggest reopening the discussion with those responsible for the restrictions as this clearly influence your work